# What is the best method for fuzzy matching all elements of a single vector or column against all the elements within that same vector or column?

Tags: r, string-matching, fuzzy-comparison

For example, if I had a data.frame such as

```r
df <- data.frame(Name = 'Chris','Christopher','John','Jon','Jonathan')
```

Is there a way for me to build a similarity matrix comparing how similar each individual name is to every other name in the 'Name' column?

I've tried using loop but not really sure how to apply this across the entire column

```r
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$distance[i] <- adist(df$Name[i], df$Name[i+1])
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://www.statology.org/fuzzy-matching-in-r/ The fuzzyjoin package looks like it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got @zephryl 's solution to work with some minor edits.

```
df <- data.frame('Name' = c('Chris','Christopher','John','Jon','Jonathan'))

distances <- adist(df$Name)
distances <- as.data.frame(distances)
rownames(distances) <- df$Name
colnames(distances) <- df$Name

distances
```

Comment: This is the answer I get:  `      Chris
Chris     0`

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the `for` loop -- `adist()` can do this directly:

```
distances <- adist(df$Name)
rownames(distances) <- df$Name
colnames(distances) <- df$Name

distances
```

```
            Chris Christopher John Jon Jonathan
Chris           0           6    5   5        8
Christopher     6           0    9  10        9
John            5           9    0   1        4
Jon             5          10    1   0        5
Jonathan        8           9    4   5        0
```

Or use `stringdist::stringdistmatrix()`, which yields a `dist` object and has additional options, e.g., choice of distance metric:

```
library(stringdist)

stringdistmatrix(df$Name, method = "jaccard")
```

```
          1         2         3         4
2 0.4444444                              
3 0.8750000 0.8181818                    
4 1.0000000 0.9090909 0.2500000          
5 0.9000000 0.7500000 0.3333333 0.5000000
```

Comment: `adist(df)`? - Doesn't work with `distances <-adist(df$Name)`